# Plotting live data using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was trying to make graph using `matplotlib`. it shows error:

```
ani=animation.FuncAnimation(f,animate, interval=1000)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1703, in __init__
    TimedAnimation.__init__(self, fig, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1465, in __init__
    event_source = fig.canvas.new_timer()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'new_timer'
```

My code:

```
 f = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100)
    a = f.add_subplot(111)


    def animate(i):
        pullData=open("ip.txt","r").read()
        dataList= pullData.split('\n')
        xList=[]
        yList=[]
        for eachLine in dataList:
            if len(eachLine)>1:
                x,y=eachLine.split(',')
                xList.append(int(x))
                yList.append(int(y))

        a.clear()
        a.plot(xList,yList)
        a.show()

    ani=animation.FuncAnimation(f,animate, interval=1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no figure canvas from which to get a timer for the animation.

Usually you would use pyplot (`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`) and let it create a figure with canvas for you via `plt.figure()` or `plt.subplots()`.

In case you don't do that you need to manually attach your figure to a canvas and in addition you would of course need to [create the GUI](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html#embedding-matplotlib-in-graphical-user-interfaces) via one of the supported Frameworks like Tk, PyQt, Wx etc.

Which route of those you want to take is not clear from the question and would depend on the final purpose of the application you create.